# How can remove the div line break and center an object at the same time using the CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have HTML code that looks like this

```html
<div class="col-md-12 alignCenter marbot50">
  <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnMakeCrtRcrdAvlble" value="Make Court Record Available" onclick="this.value = &#39;Please wait, record processing...&#39;;this.disabled = true;__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnMakeCrtRcrdAvlble&#39;,&#39;&#39;);WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnMakeCrtRcrdAvlble&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))"
    id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnMakeCrtRcrdAvlble" class="btn btn-primary" />&nbsp;
  <input src="images/help_image_clrbg.gif" onclick="Navigate('citbutton'); return false; if (typeof(Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') Page_ClientValidate(''); " name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$Image4" type="image" id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_Image4"
    title="Click &#39;Make Court Record Available&#39; to update the CIT date for this segment." style="border-width: 0px;" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSubmit" value="Submit" id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSubmit" disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-primary" />
  <input type="image" name="ImageButton" id="Image5" title="Click 'Submit' to transmit information in the form to the system." src="images/help_image_clrbg.gif" onclick="Navigate('submitbutton'); return false;" style="border-width: 0px;" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnCancel" value="Cancel" id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnCancel" class="btn btn-default" />
  <input type="image" name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$ImageButton19" id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_ImageButton19" tabindex="-1" title="Click &#39;Cancel&#39; to return back to home page. Edits to the form will not be saved."
    src="images/help_image_clrbg.gif" onclick="Navigate(&#39;cancelbutton&#39;);return false;" style="border-width:0px;" />&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>
<div class="alignCenterButton">
  <a id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkShowSegmentHistory" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$lnkShowSegmentHistory&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))">Show Segment History</a>
</div>
```

And here is how it renders on the page

[image]

The below link button 'Show segment history' I can easily center using this style

```
display: table;
margin: auto;
```

or

```
text-align: center;
```

However I also would like that button to be displayed right underneath other buttons, not with the significant vertical margins caused by DIV

I looked up the solution using Google and found this suggested styling to remove the DIV margins, which is this one

```
style="display:inline;display:flex;justify-content: center;align-items: center;"
```

However, when I apply those settings, the button no longer centers

How can I center a button and at the same time keep closer to the upper buttons/remove the div breaks?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: https://medium.com/@zac_heisey/7-alternatives-to-the-div-html-tag-7c888c7b5036#:~:text=%E2%80%9CThe%20div%20element%20has%20no,and%20easier%20maintainability%20for%20authors.%E2%80%9D .  Perhaps `label`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Remove `display:inline` style, it is not useful

```css
.alignCenterButton {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex;flex-direction:column;align-items:center;">
  <div class="col-md-12 alignCenter marbot50">
    <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnMakeCrtRcrdAvlble" value="Make Court Record Available" onclick="this.value = &#39;Please wait, record processing...&#39;;this.disabled = true;__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnMakeCrtRcrdAvlble&#39;,&#39;&#39;);WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnMakeCrtRcrdAvlble&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))"
      id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnMakeCrtRcrdAvlble" class="btn btn-primary" />&nbsp;
    <input src="images/help_image_clrbg.gif" onclick="Navigate('citbutton'); return false; if (typeof(Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') Page_ClientValidate(''); " name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$Image4" type="image" id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_Image4"
      title="Click &#39;Make Court Record Available&#39; to update the CIT date for this segment." style="border-width: 0px;" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSubmit" value="Submit" id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSubmit" disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-primary" />
    <input type="image" name="ImageButton" id="Image5" title="Click 'Submit' to transmit information in the form to the system." src="images/help_image_clrbg.gif" onclick="Navigate('submitbutton'); return false;" style="border-width: 0px;" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnCancel" value="Cancel" id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnCancel" class="btn btn-default" />
    <input type="image" name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$ImageButton19" id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_ImageButton19" tabindex="-1" title="Click &#39;Cancel&#39; to return back to home page. Edits to the form will not be saved."
      src="images/help_image_clrbg.gif" onclick="Navigate(&#39;cancelbutton&#39;);return false;" style="border-width:0px;" />&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
  </div>
  <div class="alignCenterButton">
    <a id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkShowSegmentHistory" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$lnkShowSegmentHistory&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))">Show Segment History</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. Unfortunately, the link button below didn't get any closer to the buttons above after I applied the style you suggested, still the same look and feel as I displayed on the original post